# How can I prevent a key repeating in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stdin, keypress, readline

I am writing a command-line utility with NodeJS and I want to collect raw keyboard input from a user. However I want to prevent them from long-pressing a key and that key repeating until they release the key. Each key press should only return a single character, regardless of how long the key is pressed.

Suppose I have the following code:

```js
const readline = require('readline')

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin)
process.stdin.setRawMode(true)

process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  process.stdout.write(str)
  // more code

  if (key.ctrl && key.name === 'c') {
    process.exit(0)
  }
})
```

How can I prevent key repeats?

Comment: I think the long press repeating key depends on OS setting. For Mac you could change the setting in System Preference https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-how-quickly-a-key-repeats-mchl0311bdb4/mac.  I close the key repeat and it works without changing single line of code. I guess the CLI tool is using for other users and you cannot change their computer setting. Then you could try lodash debounce. You could set the debounce timeout to proper time to prevent long pressing. However, it would be impossible to distinguish whether user is long pressing or clicking very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can store the value and set a timer to unlock if the same key is pressed. For example:

```
const readline = require("readline");

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

let lastKey = "";
let lastKeyTime = 0;

process.stdin.on("keypress", (str, key) => {
    // Check same key with time 0.6 sec
    if (lastKey == key.sequence && new Date().getTime() - lastKeyTime < 600) {
        lastKeyTime = new Date().getTime();
        return;
    }

    // Print
    process.stdout.write(str);

    // Add data
    lastKey = key.sequence;
    lastKeyTime = new Date().getTime();

    if (key.ctrl && key.name === "c") {
        process.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: I would have thought NodeJS would have had some API for preventing repeat. Your work around is fine, although setting the timeout is tricky not knowing exactly how fast people can type individual keys.

Comment: Yes, si a "hacky trick". I think the most elegant solution is a "keydown/keyup" event to make sure the key is really released. But NodeJS does not offer that. There is a lib called `iohook` but don't work in some cases :/

Comment: I'm trying to use `node-sdl` package, I create an empty window and get the events, you can find the `SDL_KEYDOWN` and get the `repeat` to know if the key is not released. The problem is you focus away from the terminal when you use SDL. So you must handle all scenarios (maybe use a script outside node to handle the terminal focus).  You show view ``node-sdl2` too. Maybe is a good option

Comment: I did some investigation, and Windows, macOS, and Linux (GNOME) all have 30 ms default key press repeat delays after an initial timeout (250 ms, 225 ms, and 500 ms respectively). A 50 ms delay between key presses is 20 characters per second or 1,200 characters per minute. If English has an average word length of 5 characters, that's a typing speed of 240 words per minute, faster than the current typing records. So setting a timeout to say 60 ms (200 wpm) seems reasonable while still catching default key repeat delays. Thanks for your help.